ubuntu has welcome sound but web browser has no sound
My new laptop installs ubuntu 24.10. However, all the browser have no sound when playing media, including chrome and firefox. But the system has beautiful welcome sound when logging in.
Thanks for your help.

No sound for one application is a symptom of the mixer muting the channel. The mixer you use may be alsamixer? Or the output device in the volume control switches after the login? My monitor doesn't have speakers, but hdmi can transport sound. I don't really know after pulseaudio was replaced by pipewire. Some people reported that the kernel module snd_soc_avs to cause issues. Trace the path where sound is the generated, where the volume is mixed, which output device is selected and where it should be played and which kernel module driver is used

After rebooting some times, the sound works.  I do not know why . Maybe I removes some software like flatpak, or removes some config file. @sleepyhead
